# Сумма введённых элементов массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как найти сумму всех элементов одномерного массива, значения которых ввел пользователь в питоне 3.x?

Comment: может сложить?..

Comment: Поиск! Надо пользоваться поиском! Это один из базовых вопросов. Он обсуждался уже много раз.

Answer (score 7):

с помощью функции `sum()`

функция на вход принимает итерируемый объект, например список `list`

пользователь может ввести символы в одной строке и тогда эту строку надо разбить на слова, слова преобразовать в список чисел и вычислить сумму этих чисел

пример кода:

```
print(sum(map(int, input().split())))
```

пользователь может ввести последовательно одно за другим `n` чисел и тогда надо все что он вводить оформить в виде списка и вычислить сумму по этому списку

пример кода:

```
print(sum(int(input()) for _ in range(n)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Есть разные способы, но предложенный [Zhihar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215489/%D0%97%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/1215490#1215490) самый быстрый. Для себя заморочился, просмотреть на время выполнения. Заполняем список из 1 000 000 элементов случайными значениями в диапазоне от 2^64 до 2^65, а затем прогоняем через 4 разных способа по 100 раз:

**EDITED** *Вынес просчет длины массива за циклы по подсказке **[CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260769/crazyelf)** (отдельное спасибо), while немного реабилитировался, но позиции в рейтинге не поменялись и добавил Numpy;)*

**EDITED 2** Спасибо за комментарий [extrn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324712/extrn), реальное повышение быстродействия:

```
import operator
import time
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
from random import randint

lst = [randint(2**64, 2**65) for _ in range(1000000)]
length = len(lst)
np_lst = np.array(lst)


def time_decorator(function):
    def accepting_args(*args):
        start_time = time.monotonic()
        for i in range(100):
            function(*args)
        print(f"--- {function.__name__} takes {(time.monotonic() - start_time)} seconds ---")
    return accepting_args


@time_decorator
def sum_list(data):
    return sum(data)


@time_decorator
def for_list(data):
    total = 0
    for ele in data:
        total += ele
    return total


@time_decorator
def reduce_list(data):
    return reduce(operator.add, data)


@time_decorator
def while_list(data, length):
    total = 0
    ele = 0
    while ele < length:
        total = total + data[ele]
        ele += 1
    return total


@time_decorator
def np_array(np_lst):
    return np.sum(np_lst)


sum_list(lst)
for_list(lst)
reduce_list(lst)
while_list(lst, length)
np_array(np_lst)
```

Результаты старых замеров:

```
--- sum_list takes 2.1900558471679688 seconds ---
--- for_list takes 5.327928066253662 seconds ---
--- reduce_list takes 9.168933391571045 seconds ---
--- while_list takes 9.949931144714355 seconds ---
--- np_array takes 0.0734705924987793 seconds ---
```

Результаты после изменений предложенных [extrn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324712/extrn):

```
--- sum_list takes 2.176893711090088 seconds ---
--- for_list takes 3.3837478160858154 seconds ---
--- reduce_list takes 3.482226610183716 seconds ---
--- while_list takes 10.27085542678833 seconds ---
--- np_array takes 2.422048568725586 seconds ---
```

Т.е. очевидно, что использование `sum` самый быстрый вариант (где-то рядом `numpy`). На втором месте перебор в цикле `for`, на третьем использование `reduce`, и, внезапно :), самый "грустный" цикл `while`

Comment: `sum` скорее всего используется не в питоничьей реализации, а в си-шной, поэтому и быстрый, а вот с `while` было удивительно

Comment: @gil9red Ничего удивительного - там `len(data)` берётся на каждой итерации. Если вынести это значение в переменную до цикла, то `while` перестаёт быть настолько грустным. Но `range` всё-равно быстрее по индексу ходит, чем если вручную индекс инкрементировать.

Comment: А самый быстрый метод на самом деле `Numpy.sum`. Если передать ему `Numpy.array`. Скорость будет на порядок больше, чем у встроенного `sum`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, а ну да, теперь это стало логичным :)

Comment: Странно, но у меня в Google Colab `sum` работает на порядок быстрее, чем у вас (поэтому я и написал, что `Numpy` на порядок быстрее, чем `sum`, а не на два порядка) %)  В остальном результаты похожие. И для `for` где используется `range` выносить `len` из цикла нет смысла, там `len` используется один раз - для создания `range`.

Comment: @CrazyElf хмм, тоже запустил на Google Colab - там только у `sum` результат отличается в лучшую сторону от моей локальной машины, у остальных методов время хуже. Даже не знаю, что сказать... А по поводу len - все равно уже посчитана, так что роли я думаю не сыграет

Comment: @SergBocharov Скорее всего там просто другие версии питона и библиотек. Там всё время что-то подпиливают, может влиять на производительность. Ну я так - уточнить для понимания, а не чтобы прикопаться )  А, и там же машина виртуальная, наверное, от процессора тоже всякое зависит, там какой-то своеобразный процессор, наверное.

Comment: `for x in data: total += x` для for, `reduce(operator.add, data)` для reduce, и `randint(2**64, 2**65)` чтобы немного сократить разрыв между sum и остальными способами. sum специализирован на небольших значениях, помещающихся в процессорный регистр, но значительно медленнее на больших (хоть и все равно лучший вариант).

Comment: @extrn спасибо за комментарий, подчерпнул для себя пару интересных моментов :)

Comment: @SergBocharov у вас судя по всему 32битная архитектура, поэтому аккумулятор переполняется на значительно меньших значениях и включается медленный режим. Поэтому на вашей машине медленнее других, и поэтому sum почти не замедлился при 2**64

Comment: @extrn нет - 64битная, причем на Google Colab такие же значения (после изменений предложенных вами)

Comment: @SergBocharov на `randint(2**64, 2**65)` будут приблизительно одинаково тупить и 32битная и 64битная версии, но на `randint(0, 1000000)` должна тормозить только 32битная. `sys.maxsize` у вас `9223372036854775807`?

Comment: @extrn `sys.maxsize 9223372036854775807`

Comment: @SergBocharov ну тогда, возможно, по какой-то причине в вашей сборке выставлен [этот дефайн](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2332). Науке это неизвестно :)

Comment: @extrn, возможно скрипт в виртуальном окружении для стака - а там каких только пакетов только не установлено )))